# Firebase SPM getting error with Device - Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

In one of my project, required google login integration. So used SPM for Firebase(9.6.0) and GoogleSignIn(7.0.0).
Google sign in works well in iOS simulator but gives an error while running in device.

**Error:**

-> Webkit is not available for building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for macOS, file 'GoogleSignIn' for architecture x86_64

[image]

I tried solutions in this given [link](https://AIzaSyBuiHPaFAPH4Ec9BxQ0x5UEck) but still the same error. If I run the same project with Xcode 14 then it works well with both simulator and device.

Is there any solution regarding this ?

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code/error, please add the actual code and error message to the question as text. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you for the suggestion. But I found that the issue is with xcode version. So update the xcode will resolve my problem.

Comment: Good to know that it's solved and that you have posted the solution, but that won't make this solution easy to locate by future visitors if you don't post the error messages as text.

Comment: @SandraRossi I update the question by adding error message as text. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

**Above mentioned Issue Resolved**

There is an issue with Xcode version of 14.2. Because I tried so many things which is suggested on google.

But then I tried to run the app with **Xcode 14.3.1** and it works perfect in both simulator and device.